# "Bros." pronunciation: "brothers", /bɹɒs/, or plural of "bro"?

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations

I know that the slang word "bro" is /bɹoʊz/ or /bɹʌz/ in plural.

Then there are groups like Moss Bros. or a band called Bros that people do use /bɹɒs/.

People I see when I Google search this have said that they prefer to pronounce "Bros." in full form.

What's the use consensus?

Comment: For me, Bros. in a name (in your example "the Moss Brothers") is always spoken as "Brothers".

Comment: I agree with @user3169 , except for rare cases when I'm intentionally saying it in short form either to be silly or to emphasize the abbreviation.  I would get annoyed if someone consistently said "bros" instead of "brothers" for this case.

Answer (score 4):

*Bros.* with a period after it, which is showing it to be an abbreviation such as in a name like your example of *Moss Bros.*, is pronounced *Brothers*.

However, *bro's* is also a slang term for brothers, usually meaning close group of friends that feel like brothers, is said as if it's its own word.

> Warner Bros. = Warner Brothers
>   You guys are my bros = You guys are my bros.